# React Native: Absolute bottom text input

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I can't for the life of me get this text input to display absolutely positioned at the bottom of my screen.

This is my very basic setup:

```
class Chat extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.content}>
            <Text>Test</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.footer}>
            <Text>Meow</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#F5F5F5",
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: { paddingTop: 30 }
    }),
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  footer: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    padding:10,
    position: 'absolute',
    flex:0.1,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  }
}
```

I've also tried switching the flex attribute of the footer to a fixed height: 80, but I still get the same output. How do I get the footer to be at the bottom?

Also keep in mind this is using React Navigation and this is a StackNavigator screen - not sure if that matters.

[image]

Comment: Ugh, this is because i'm using shoutem ui. If i move the Text and View component imports back to react-native, it seems to work...

Comment: You should check [this](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/components/typography) documentation for the Text components and [this](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/ui-toolkit/components/view) documentation for View components when using the Shoutem UI Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with styling .. You need the flex of container to be 1 then inside the container there are two views which are of flex:1 and flex:0.1 so it seems that it's impossible to make it with this configuration, let's try something else:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#F5F5F5",
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: { paddingTop: 30 }
    }),
  },
  content: {
    flex: 0.8,
  },
  footer: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    padding:10,
    flex:0.2,
  }
}
```

Basically, I divided the screen into the ratio of 8:2 which in total is 1 i.e, 8 parts of content view and 2 parts of footer view.

Cheers :)